# Consuming JSON Array From WCF From Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, wcf, gson

So, I am sitting with a bit of a problem! I am trying to consume one of the methods from my WCF. I have plenty of different methods from the WCF that I am consuming with no problem, however, I am struggling with this one in particular.

Now, the response I am getting from my service is;

```
{
"GetUserProfileResult":
    {
"City":"Viborg",
"Country":"Danmark",
"FirstName":"Jens",
"Floor":"1",
"HouseNumber":"Vejnavnet",
"LastName":"Hansen",
"MiddleName":"Hans",
"Phone":"12345678",
"StreetName":"Vejnavnet",
"ZipCode":"8800"
    }
}
```

I then have a wrapper class set up like so;

```
public class UserWrapper {
    public String City;
    public String Country;
    public String FirstName;
    public String Floor;
    public String HouseNumber;
    public String LastName;
    public String MiddleName;
    public String Phone;
    public String StreetName;
    public String ZipCode;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "First Name: " + FirstName + ". Middle Name: " + MiddleName + ". Last Name: " + LastName + ". Streetname: " + StreetName + ". Housenumber: " + HouseNumber + ". City: " + City +
                ". Zipcode: " + ZipCode + ". Country: " + Country + ". Phone: " + Phone + ".";
    }

}
```

Now, I am guessing that the way, I am trying to consume it - through my AsyncTask class is where the problem is. However, I have tried 10 different ways to do this, and it still will not work. Currently I am trying this;

```
private boolean getUserProfile(String email) {
        try {
            gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            URL url = new URL("http://website.servicelocation.com/Service1.svc/GetUserProfile/" + email);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((urlConnection.getInputStream())));
            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
            List<String> yourList = new Gson().fromJson(in, listType);
            if (yourList != null) {
                for (String s : yourList) {
                    Log.d("List Contents", s);
                }
               return true;
            }
            Log.d("Error", "GetProfile Error");
            return false;
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            mue.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But that just gives me a;

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

I have tried doing it like so;

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Post>>(){}.getType();
List<Post> posts = (List<UserWrapper>) gson.fromJson(in, listType);
```

But this throws the same exception. Any help will be greatly appreciated, as I am starting to pull out my hairs here! :P

EDIT 1:

Trying to parse it directly as an object like so;

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((urlConnection.getInputStream())));
            Log.d("in:", in.readLine());
            UserWrapper uw = gson.fromJson(in, UserWrapper.class);
            if (uw != null) {
                    Log.d("UserWrapper Content:", uw.toString());
               return true;
            }
            Log.d("Error", "GetProfile Error");
            return false;
```

And adding;

```
public String GetUserProfileResult;
```

in the wrapper class, also does not work.

EDIT 2:

So as it turns out, I was not trying to consume an array, but an object. That was what was causing the headache. I failed to mention, that I have access to the webservice, so I just rewrote the WCF service, so that it returns a `List<string>` instead of an instance of my `User` class. Then I got it to work. Thanks to the guy who tried to help, me - and when his answer didn't work, deleted his answer and downvoted my question.

Comment: Looking at the `Error` and the `JSON Object` I believe that `JSON` is an Object. So, why are you trying to get an `ARRAY` when in fact it's an `OBJECT` ?

Comment: I have tried parsing it as an object as well, but I can't seem to get it to work. If I add GetUserProfileResult to the Wrapper and make a `UserWrapper iw = gson.fromJson(in, UserWrapper.class);` line, I still get an exception thrown at me.

Comment: Can you Log `in` and paste the result? Looking at this `"http://website.servicelocation.com/Service1.svc/GetUserProfile/" + email` I believe it's a request to get info of a particular user right?

Comment: `D/in:: {"GetUserProfileResult":{"City":"Viborg","Country":"Danmark","FirstName":"Jens","Floor":"1","HouseNumber":"Vejnavnet","LastName":"Hansen","MiddleName":"Hans","Phone":"12345678","StreetName":"Vejnavnet","ZipCode":"8800"}}` - Done with a `in.readLine()`

Comment: Why are you doing this [(List<UserWrapper>) ] it is suppose to be object look at your response it has object than in object another object of wrapperclass no array

Comment: You want to bind the `JSON Object` to your `POJO` right?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I want to do, so I can set some TextView's.